# Exporting .PST to named folders in two locations based in property values

Tags: powershell, if-statement

Hello I am still green with PS and need some assistance.

Please note: this is also the first time asking a question here so please be kind :)

I have bulk group of users that I need to Export the .pst to \file\location however if the user is in litigation hold I need to put the .pst in an ALT location. I have managed to setup a script that will create the folder in the \file\location with the users name and date and then export the .pst to that file. that is working

```
$Users = Get-Content "C:\Disabledusers.csv"
$date = Get-Date
$date = $date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
ForEach ($user in $users){ $newPath = Join-Path "\\network-location\t$\Users$" -childpath "$user $date"
New-Item $newPath -type directory}

ForEach ($user in $users){ New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $user -FilePath \\network- location\t$\Users$\"$user $date"\$user.pst}
```

Now what I am trying to do is check each user to see if the LitigationHoldEnabled = True do that same process in \file\location2

This is where I am stuck

```
$Users = Get-Content "C:\Disabledusers.csv"
$date = Get-Date
$date = $date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")

ForEach ($user in $users) {Get-Mailbox $user | Select-Object LitigationHoldEnabled}

if(???) 
     {$newPath = Join-Path "\\network-location\t$\Users$\Legalhold" -childpath "$user $date"
New-Item $newPath -type directory 

New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $user -FilePath \\network-location\t$\Users$\Legalhold\"$user $date"\$user.pst}
 
else 
{$newPath = Join-Path "\\network-location\t$\Users$" -childpath "$user $date"
New-Item $newPath -type directory

New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $user -FilePath \\network-location\t$\Users$\"$user $date"\$user.pst}
```

Any help or hints would be great
Thanks
-Sean

Comment: Hi Sean. So you are putting an additional copy in the alt location? The way you worded it sounds like it’s either or but the code indicates it’s both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to export those without litigation hold to the first path and for those with `LitigationHoldEnabled` flagged to the LegalHold path. You can combine all steps into the following.

```
$Users = Get-Content "C:\Disabledusers.csv"
$date = Get-Date
$date = $date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
ForEach ($user in $users)
{

    if((Get-Mailbox $user).litigationholdenabled -eq $true)
    {
        $newPath = Join-Path "\\network-location\t$\Users$\Legalhold" -childpath "$user $date"
        $null = New-Item $newPath -ItemType directory
        $exportpath = Join-Path $newPath "$user.pst"
        New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $user -FilePath $exportpath
    }
    else
    {

        $newPath = Join-Path "\\network-location\t$\Users$" -childpath "$user $date"
        $null = New-Item $newPath -ItemType directory
        $exportpath = Join-Path $newPath "$user.pst"
        New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $user -FilePath $exportpath
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Doug, thank you for your response the end goal it to separate the two groups..  

Folder A = only legal hold
Folder B = everyone else.

Comment: You Sir are my hero, works exactly as needed... Thank you again for your help!!

Comment: Please consider accepting it as the solution by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Sorry, Like I said.. First time asking Questions here.. I know I will have more

Checked as answered